# Typesetting lyrics alternating between two characters

Tags: songs

I'm researching optimal and good looking ways to typeset a musical lyric which two characters sing one after the other. An example screenshot taken from a Word document:

[image: example from a Word document]

As seen the two characters start singing together and then split in alternating lines. How could I achieve such typesetting with proper LaTeX manners?
I've explored the songbook and verse packages but none offers a a proper solution.

Comment: Though I did answer this question, in general it is preferred if the questioner shows some own efforts in what he tried so far. Even if no code from that attempt will be kept in an answer, it saves any answerer from typing the lyrics or creating a complete MWE. The hurdle to answer is lowered this way and you might get more or better answers.

Comment: @Skillmon you are right, I always try to give as much as possible but in this specific case I didn't t manage to achieve anything. I could have indeed at least type the text ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about typesetting it in a `tabular` environment (with some different syntax added, for convenience):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{duett}[4]
  {%
    \def#1##1{##1&\\}%
    \def#3##1{&##1\\}%
    \begin{tabular}
      {
        @{}
        *2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
        @{}
      }
      \MakeUppercase{#2} & \MakeUppercase{#4}\\\\
  }
  {%
    \end{tabular}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \MakeUppercase{Igor} \& \MakeUppercase{Frederick}\\[\bigskipamount]
  Di nuovo assiem come non mai,\\
  il nostro sogno ora è qui.
\end{center}
\bigskip
\begin{duett}{\fr}{Frederick}{\ig}{Igor}
  \fr{Come Stanlio e Ollio}
  \ig{L'arabia e il petrolio}
  \fr{Come Franco e Ciccio}
  \ig{Il ragù nel pasticcio}
\end{duett}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Generalized

As somewhat promised, the generalized version. The environment takes one argument which should be a comma separated list containing `\<cs>=<Name>` pairs. You can additionally provide a `*` after `\begin{multilyrics}` (so `\begin{multilyrics}*`). If you do that instead of a `tabular` the lyrics are displayed in a `description`. I used `xparse` and the `expl3` programming language to implement this. You can ignore `>>>` and `<<<`, those are just fold marks in my VIM.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\charactertablestyle[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_clist
\int_new:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_int
\int_new:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_current_char_int
\tl_new:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_names_tl
\tl_new:N \l__maxiride_key_tl
\tl_new:N \l__maxiride_val_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { o }
\cs_new:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_pre_eq:w #1 = #2 \q_stop%>>>
  {
    #1
  }%<<<
\cs_new:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_post_eq:w #1 = #2 \q_stop%>>>
  {
    #2
  }%<<<
\cs_new:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars:n #1%>>>
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__maxiride_key_tl
      {
        \tl_trim_spaces:o { \__maxiride_multilyrics_pre_eq:w #1 \q_stop }
      }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__maxiride_val_tl 
      {
        \tl_trim_spaces:o { \__maxiride_multilyrics_post_eq:w #1 \q_stop }
      }
    \exp_args:NVV \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_aux:nn
      \l__maxiride_key_tl
      \l__maxiride_val_tl
  }%<<<
\cs_new:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_desc:nn #1 #2%>>>
  {
    \cs_set:Npn #1 ##1 { \item [ #2: ] ##1 }
  }%<<<
\cs_new:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_ampersands:n #1%>>>
  {
    \exp_not:n { & }
  }%<<<
\cs_new:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_tab:nn #1 #2%>>>
  {
    \int_incr:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_current_char_int
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_names_tl
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_names_tl { & } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_names_tl
      { \charactertablestyle { #2 } }
    \cs_set:Npx #1 ##1
      {
        \int_step_function:nnN
          { 2 } { \l__maxiride_multilyrics_current_char_int }
          \__maxiride_multilyrics_ampersands:n
        ##1
        \int_step_function:nnN
          { \l__maxiride_multilyrics_current_char_int + \c_one_int }
          { \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_int }
          \__maxiride_multilyrics_ampersands:n
        \exp_not:N \\
      }
  }%<<<
\NewDocumentEnvironment { multilyrics } { s m }
  {% begin >>>
    \clist_set:Nn \l__maxiride_multilyrics_clist { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_int
      { \clist_count:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_clist }
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN
          \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_aux:nn
          \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_desc:nn
        \cs_set:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_env_begin:
          {
            \begin { description }
          }
        \cs_set:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_env_end: { \end { description } }
      }
      {
        \int_zero:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_current_char_int
        \tl_clear:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_names_tl
        \cs_set_eq:NN
          \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_aux:nn
          \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars_tab:nn
        \cs_set:Npx \__maxiride_multilyrics_env_begin:
          {
            \exp_not:N \begin { tabular }
              {
                @{}
                *{ \int_use:N \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_int }
                 {
                   >{ \exp_not:n { \centering \arraybackslash } }
                   p{
                     \dim_eval:n
                      {
                        \linewidth / \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_int
                        + 2\tabcolsep
                        - (\l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_int\tabcolsep)*2
                      }
                    }
                 }
                @{}
              }
            \exp_not:n { \l__maxiride_multilyrics_chars_names_tl \\ \\ }
          }
        \cs_set:Npn \__maxiride_multilyrics_env_end: { \end { tabular } }
      }
    \clist_map_function:NN
      \l__maxiride_multilyrics_clist
      \__maxiride_multilyrics_def_chars:n
    \__maxiride_multilyrics_env_begin:
  }%<<<
  {% end >>>
    \__maxiride_multilyrics_env_end:
  }%<<<
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \MakeUppercase{Igor} \& \MakeUppercase{Frederick}\\[\bigskipamount]
  Di nuovo assiem come non mai,\\
  il nostro sogno ora è qui.
\end{center}
\bigskip
\begin{multilyrics}*{\fr=Frederick,\ig=Igor}
  \fr{Come Stanlio e Ollio}
  \ig{L'arabia e il petrolio}
  \fr{Come Franco e Ciccio}
  \ig{Il ragù nel pasticcio}
\end{multilyrics}

\bigskip
\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{multilyrics}{\fr=Frederick,\ig=Igor,\ha=Hans}
  \fr{Come Stanlio e Ollio}
  \ha{Foooo}
  \ig{L'arabia e il petrolio}
  \ha{Foooobaar}
  \fr{Come Franco e Ciccio}
  \ig{Il ragù nel pasticcio}
  \ha{Baaar de Baz}
\end{multilyrics}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort, while this indeed achieve a desired output it is however too much an ad-hoc solution while instead I was looking for a generalized approach for a variable amount of lyric lines and characters speaking. Anyway I start to think that this is a close as we can get, further ctan browsing didn't held anything specialized for this.

Comment: @Maxiride generalizing it is not a problem. But the columns will get rather narrow with many characters. Could provide two styles, one tabular and one `description` version, if you like.

Comment: @Maxiride if the lyrics need to span more than one page in the `tabular` approach I could as well change it to use `longtable`.

Comment: the generalized approach proposed works perfectly for the needs I'm facing thank you very very much for the contribution! What you did with expl3 is beyond back magic for me though and didn't even knew that existed, I'll have a look at it to know more. A longtable won't be needed as I sincerely doubt to ever encounter such a long duet.

Comment: @Maxiride you can just replace `tabular` with `longtable` and load the package, if you ever need it.